# Need advice installing python-oauth2 for python3 on OS X

Tags: oauth, python-3.x

I have downloaded this library on OS X:
https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2

when I try to install it, I get this error:

$sudo python3 setup.py install

File "setup.py", line 18
    print "unable to find version in %s" % (VERSIONFILE,)
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

---

What do I do to get past this?

Here's the setup.py file for reference: https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2/blob/master/setup.py

Answer (score 3):

oauth2 evidently does not support Python 3. Contact the author and discuss what can be done about that. Porting [may be simple](http://python3porting.com/) and is often fun!

Comment: running `2to3 -w .` in the python-oauth2 directory fixes it so that it can be installed easily.

I'll see if I can refactor all of it and submit a patch, but that should get them going (if they are still interested).